# ts-pattern, why does enum matching not work?

Tags: typescript

I'm using [ts-pattern](https://github.com/gvergnaud/ts-pattern) to do pattern matching. I have an enum

```
enum PossibleSelections {
  EQUAL = 'equal',
  AVERAGE = 'average',
  LOWEST = 'lowest',
  CUSTOM = 'custom',
}
```

And a selection handler

```
const handleOnSelect = (newSelection: PossibleSelections) => {
    match({ newSelection })
      .with({ newSelection: PossibleSelections.CUSTOM }, () => {
        ...do something
      })
      .with({ newSelection: PossibleSelections.AVERAGE }, () => {
        ...do something
      })
      .with({ newSelection: PossibleSelections.LOWEST }, () => {
        ...do something
      })
      .with({ newSelection: PossibleSelections.EQUAL }, () => {
        ...do something
      });
  };
```

however none of the "do something" code runs. I've logged the `newSelection` and can see that it outputs the selection. If I select custom and run `console.log(newSelection, PossibleSelections.CUSTOM, typeof newSelection, typeof PossibleSelections.CUSTOM)`, I get `custom custom string string`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it isn't clear what `match` accepts as parameters and I'm assuming `with` represents a conditional, you can try something like this

```
enum PossibleSelections {
  EQUAL = "equal",
  AVERAGE = "average",
  LOWEST = "lowest",
  CUSTOM = "custom"
}
const str = (val: keyof typeof PossibleSelections) =>
  `do something ${val}` as const;
const handleOnSelect = (
  newSelection: keyof typeof PossibleSelections
):
  | "do something EQUAL"
  | "do something AVERAGE"
  | "do something LOWEST"
  | "do something CUSTOM"
  | null => {
  switch (newSelection) {
    case "CUSTOM": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    case "AVERAGE": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    case "EQUAL": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    case "LOWEST": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    default: {
      return null;
    }
  }
};
```

If you'd rather have the values be returned by passing in the keys, then tweak the `str` helper function to  pass the key into the enum object directly

```
// mapper is an array of strings
// const chunkedDocumentIds = chunkArray(mapper, 11000);
enum PossibleSelections {
  EQUAL = "equal",
  AVERAGE = "average",
  LOWEST = "lowest",
  CUSTOM = "custom"
}
const str = (val: keyof typeof PossibleSelections) =>
  `do something ${PossibleSelections[val]}` as const;
  

const handleOnSelect = (
  newSelection: keyof typeof PossibleSelections
):
  | "do something equal"
  | "do something average"
  | "do something lowest"
  | "do something custom"
  | null => {
  switch (newSelection) {
    case "CUSTOM": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    case "AVERAGE": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    case "EQUAL": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    case "LOWEST": {
      return str(newSelection);
    }
    default: {
      return null;
    }
  }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACg9gZwQSwEYBtgGViYMYAuycICUA3gLABQUdAogIoCqAggDJQC8UA5MAEcwAQ3S8ANDTpRWANXoAlVgHF63PsIBuwAE7CA5sAlS67APIB1elgAq63ujgB3YAgLHadAMLNbZgLL2eGBucBAeAL40NAD0MVA6wARgOiBQANbAAJ5kNHgkblBuOuoAFJqiAFwZ2XAAZlAEWQAOwPWwiCgY2LjAhMSkAJTcAHxQAAYAJnBFYUkAFsgg%20lAAJOQV6BHjUMJk%20aQEANx5BQRQ88Igk5hmIDj45zylIMBOD31EJNWZWe1NrXa8CQaEwH36BUG1QARNNZhAFksVkw2OxoVAAD5QWEzBBzAiLZYyeRKVTorE4%20GIonmKy2cnYuF4hEEpFQHx%20fwM8DodCjCgmIpOZAEPDzKAvN7gr4gYZUTzSKB4PbAbEcmwBaHVeWK3WJZKpIoEHSS969CGyk4K6QRJUq7FyRQqehagXWvVJFJpYqm6UDQZW3VQW3KhCq6EojiunVBuj6r1Gk2vM2Pf2B3Uh%203Q2nWGzRwVB%20OGn3Jv0kAMFui2ybAOrCMDoAjahKew08vkRdPBmhRaixeJFtKbMCuKAAWjHUGaezIBNVoEgUCWjRmwjweGAzXOvzIy-GxRscFkonGp0OicPx75z02P1qDQBbQawK6YPNMoQwy4IxMU1x%20MJFZ1hfUEelTAoAG1NgAXW2XZ9jOK0z0KS5rlue530vUQyhMUt3wGO8-gfFonw6EFujLUgaChEwKSZAC2UEER0GhWjGX-FlAN2bQ9EMVjPDojjqRWRwXDcfi6EEqlWSJYJQggCTMSgdt%20RjBBhVFcVfXw8s3UVUNw3VTVtUrFsDW9Y0sPQbTwMtAte30rNHVJF0TPdMyEwPI9RBsz403sgsDOxSM0TcwtWwsnQrN8i0K2tBzpCC7NLFzfN3MHC9vOsvDbLixUEroGs6wbJs9I9czlIbdAu27Txe07GggA)